# Error while using node passport authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using passport for authentication in my application. When I try to initialize passport I am getting an error. I am using express for building my application. I have corr

Here is my app.js file
app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
 var login = require('./routes/login');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var db = require('./db.js');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var fetch = require('./routes/collect');
var passport = require('passport');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/login',login.user);
app.get('/collect',fetch.collect);
app.post('/auth', urlencodedParser, auth.authentication);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I am getting this error

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
                 ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'initialize'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kurakar/workspace/mywork/app.js:26:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I have correctly defined passport module in `./routes/auth.js` file.

**PS:**
When I install passport and passport-local using `npm install --save passport` and `npm install --save passport-local` it shows only these line:

```
passport@0.2.1 node_modules/passport
├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
└── pause@0.0.1

passport-local@1.0.0 node_modules/passport-local
└── passport-strategy@1.0.0
```

Comment: You need to setup a strategy before you initialize.

Comment: I used this code to setup strategy `var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Stratagy;` on `./routes/auth.js`.

Comment: And you added it to passport with `passport.use`?

Comment: No, I have used only 'app.use(passport.initialize());'

Comment: http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

Comment: Sorry, I have used that in my auth.js file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77921/discussion-between-user85544-and-ben-fortune).